# Invalid parameter implementing GetMenuItemInfoW with JNA

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I am invoking the win32 API function `GetMenuItemInfoW`. When I invoke the function I it returns `false`, and `Native.getLastError()` returns 87:

`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 87 (0x57)  The parameter is incorrect.`

I think that my error is in my implementation of the structure MenuItemInfoW:

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({"cbSize", "fMask", "fType", "fState", "wId", "hSubMenu", "hBmpChecked", "hBmpUnchecked", "dwItemData", "dwTypeData", "cch", "hbmpItem"})
public class MENUITEMINFOW extends Structure {
   public int cbSize;
   public int fMask;
   public int fType;
   public int fState;
   public int wId;
   public Pointer hSubMenu;
   public Pointer hBmpChecked;
   public Pointer hBmpUnchecked;
   public WinDef.ULONGByReference dwItemData;
   public WString dwTypeData;
   public int cch;
   public Pointer hbmpItem;

   public MENUITEMINFOW() {
       super();
   }

   public MENUITEMINFOW(Pointer pointer) {
      super(pointer);
   }
}
```

And this is my code for invoking the function:

```
MENUITEMINFOW menuiteminfow = new MENUITEMINFOW();
menuiteminfow.fMask = 0x00000040 | 0x00000080 | 0x00000004 | 0x00000002;
menuiteminfow.fType = 0x00000000;
menuiteminfow.cch = 256;
menuiteminfow.dwTypeData = new WString(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(256, " ")));
menuiteminfow.cbSize = Native.getNativeSize(menuiteminfow.getClass());

WinDef.BOOL result = User32Ex.INSTANCE.GetMenuItemInfoW(hMenu.getPointer(), 0, true, menuiteminfow.getPointer());
if (!result.booleanValue()) {
   int errorCode = Native.getLastError();
   System.out.println("Error Code: " + errorCode);
}
```

I have edited my editing my code for your tip, but I get the same error 87. This is my new code:

```
MENUITEMINFOW menuiteminfow = new MENUITEMINFOW();                                                                                                 
menuiteminfow.fMask = 0x00000040 | 0x00000080 | 0x00000004 | 0x00000002;                                                                           
menuiteminfow.fType = 0x00000000;                                                                                                                  
menuiteminfow.cch = 0;                                                                                                                             
menuiteminfow.dwTypeData = Pointer.NULL;                                                                                                           
menuiteminfow.cbSize = Native.getNativeSize(menuiteminfow.getClass());                                                                             
                                                                                                                                               
WinDef.BOOL result = User32Ex.INSTANCE.GetMenuItemInfoW(hMenu.getPointer(), 
new WinDef.UINT(0), new WinDef.BOOL(true), menuiteminfow.getPointer());
if (!result.booleanValue()) {                                                                                                                      
   int errorCode = Native.getLastError();                                                                                                         
   System.out.println("Error Code: " + errorCode);                                                                                                
}
```

And this is new version of my structure:

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({"cbSize", "fMask", "fType", "fState", "wId", "hSubMenu", "hBmpChecked", "hBmpUnchecked", "dwItemData", "dwTypeData", "cch", "hbmpItem"})
public class MENUITEMINFOW extends Structure {                                                                                                                 
    public int cbSize;                                                                                                                                         
    public int fMask;                                                                                                                                          
    public int fType;                                                                                                                                          
    public int fState;                                                                                                                                         
    public int wId;                                                                                                                                            
    public Pointer hSubMenu;                                                                                                                                   
    public Pointer hBmpChecked;                                                                                                                                
    public Pointer hBmpUnchecked;                                                                                                                              
    public BaseTSD.LONG_PTR dwItemData;                                                                                                                        
    public Pointer dwTypeData;                                                                                                                                 
    public int cch;                                                                                                                                            
    public WinDef.HBITMAP hbmpItem;                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                           
    public MENUITEMINFOW() {                                                                                                                                   
       super();                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                           
    public MENUITEMINFOW(Pointer pointer) {                                                                                                                    
       super(pointer);                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                           
       this.read();                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure mapping can be improved.

First, a `ULONG_PTR` is not the same as a `WinDef.ULONGByReference`.  The `ULONG_PTR` is a pointer-sized value, but it does not actually point to anything.

JNA has a built-in `BaseTSD.LONG_PTR` type which you could use here.

While a `Pointer` technically works for `hbmpItem` and the other bitmap fields, the type `WinDef.HBITMAP` is already defined in JNA so you should use that mapping.

Finally, and the likely cause of your error, `dwTypeData` receives a String, but it is a buffer that you need to allocate and fill.  From the [MENUITEMINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-menuiteminfow) docs:

> To retrieve a menu item of type `MFT_STRING`, first find the size of the string by setting the `dwTypeData` member of `MENUITEMINFO` to `NULL` and then calling `GetMenuItemInfo`. The value of `cch+1` is the size needed. Then allocate a buffer of this size, place the pointer to the buffer in `dwTypeData`, increment `cch`, and call `GetMenuItemInfo` once again to fill the buffer with the string.

So in this case, you'd want to map a `Pointer` to `dwTypeData`, call the function the first time with that pointer set to `Pointer.NULL`, and then alloating memory for it based on incrementing `cch`:

```
menuiteminfow.cch++; 
// allocate 2 bytes per widechar
menuiteminfow.dwTypeData = new Memory(cch * 2);
```

You can fetch the string from there after the function call with `menuiteminfow.dwTypeData.getWideString()`.

Comment: Irrespective of the fact, that a `LONG` is 32 bits wide on Windows, a `ULONG_PTR` is *always* pointer-sized. Also, regardless of the `dw` prefix in `dwItemData`, this member is allowed (and indeed commonly used) to store a pointer to arbitrary user-defined data.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. Every time I mention that type in an answer I tend to mess it up. You'd think I'd have learned it by now.